# Establish the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}=\frac12$

Tags: real-analysis

> Use either the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit or Sequential Criterion for limits to establish the following limit.
>   $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I tried the following but someone pointed out that there is an issue because the triangle inequality is not a reversible process. I am wondering why that is entirely true seeing as the inequalities seem to be true regardless.
$$\left| \frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left| \frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{3}{2} \right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left| \frac{x^2}{x+1} \right| - \left|\frac{3}{2} \right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left| \frac{x^2}{x+1} \right| < \epsilon + \frac{3}{2}$$
$$\left| \frac{x^2 -1}{x+1} \right| < \epsilon + \frac{3}{2}$$
$$\left| {x-1}\right| < \epsilon + \frac{3}{2}=\delta$$

Since we are able to find a $\delta>0$ for any $\epsilon>0$ the limit is established.

Comment: First mistake: $$\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}\ne \frac{x^2}{x+1} -1$$

Comment: Is it not true that $\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1} = \frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{x+1}{x+1} = \frac{x^2}{x+1} - 1$. I'm missing the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you go from$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x+1}-\frac32\right|<\varepsilon$$to$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right|-\left|\frac32\right|<\varepsilon?$$

Comment: No it is not true because $$x^2-x+1\ne x^2-(x+1)$$

Comment: applied the triangle inequality, $\left| \frac{x^2}{x+1} \right| - \left| \frac{3}{2} \right| \leq \left| \frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{3}{2} \right|$

Comment: Start with $|\frac {x^2 - 2 + 1}{x+1}-\frac 12|=|\frac {2x^2 - 2x + 2 - (x+1)}{2(x+1)}|$  Simplify, factor and see where it takes you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\dfrac{x^2 -x+1}{x+1} -\dfrac{1}{2}| =$

$|\dfrac{2[((x-1)x +1)]-x-1}{2(x+1)}|=$

$|\dfrac{2(x-1)x -(x-1)}{2(x+1)}|=$

$|\dfrac{(x-1)(2x-1)}{2(x+1)}| =:|f(x)|$

Let $0<x<2 $,  I.e $|x-1| <1.$

$|f(x)| \lt |\dfrac{(x-1)(3)}{2}|.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta < \min(1, 2\epsilon/3).$

Then $ |x-1| < \delta$ implies

$|f(x)|< 3\delta /2 < \epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

We may write 
$$
\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1-(x+1)+3}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}-1+\frac{3}{x+1}=x-2+\frac{3}{x+1}.
$$
By additivity of limits, it suffices to show 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{3}{x+1}=\frac{3}{2},
$$
and to do this it suffices to show 
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x+1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}.
$$
Can you go from here?